# Is there a method to selectively apply Bootstrap classes to specific sections of a pre-built website without altering the existing styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

Is there a recommended approach in Bootstrap to apply specific Bootstrap classes to particular blocks or to change the default classes, such as modifying .row to .row_2, without affecting the existing elements styled differently with classes used in Bootstrap?

Comment: You might be looking on [how to override bootstrap in css](https://marketsplash.com/tutorials/css/how-to-override-bootstrap-css/).

Answer (score 0):

Probably You are looking for Bootstrap Customization.
This can be achieved via sass customization and recompile.

For more info:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCX3QVl_PiI

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zfXae4kyxAs